# Missing Days from GA4 BigQuery Export

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics, google-analytics-4

My GA4 daily export has various missing days. It seems like its happened to various users however Ive not seen any solution to this. Please assist

Daily export is working, it has some days, but not others. I have not reached the daily 1 million line data export limit